# Position objects inside of a container

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Newbie flutter question.

So I am looking at the most efficient way of positioning widgets inside of a container; I am asking this because I find widgets like stack very hardwiring and positioning it to the pixel. I want to understand better ways of trying to position this widget.

This method is being called inside of a statefulWidget.

```
 Widget myContainer() {
    double c_width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7;

    var logo = Icon(
      Icons.local_florist,
      color: Colors.lightBlue,
      size: 40.0,
    );
    var pitchLine1 = Text(
      'Starter line',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0),
      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
    );

    var pitchLine2 = Text(
      'Starter line 2',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0),
      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
    );

    var valueProp = Text(
      'All Stars. Increase your sales and understand your customers better with Great Reviews.',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
    );

    var conditionsApply = Text(
      'By continuing, you agree to ReviewPro\'s Terms of Use and Privacy Policy',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    );

    return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 5,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 35.0, top: 25.0, right: 35.0, bottom: 35.0),
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Positioned(
                    top: 10,
                    left: 5,
                    child: logo,
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 50,
                    left: 5,
                    height: 40,
                    width: c_width,
                    child: pitchLine1,
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 90,
                    left: 5,
                    height: 40,
                    width: c_width,
                    child: pitchLine2,
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 150,
                    left: 5,
                    height: 20,
                    width: c_width,
                    child: valueProp,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 5,
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 35.0, top: 20.0, right: 35.0, bottom: 10.0),
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Positioned(
                    top: 20,
                    left: 5,
                    width: 300,
//                    height: 20,
                    child: TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Login with Google Credentials',
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Colors.white),
                      autofocus: true,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 150,
                    left: 5,
                    width: 300,
//                    height:30,
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        child: Text("Sign up "),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            new MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => new ReviewProSkeleton()),
                          );

                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 250,
                    left: 5,
                    width: c_width,
//                    height: 20,
                    child: conditionsApply,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

}

[image: This is what is being populated by the above widget]

Comment: see `Alignment` class - the docs say: *"A point within a rectangle.

Alignment(0.0, 0.0) represents the center of the rectangle. The distance from -1.0 to +1.0 is the distance from one side of the rectangle to the other side of the rectangle. Therefore, 2.0 units horizontally (or vertically) is equivalent to the width (or height) of the rectangle. [...]"*

Comment: so I realised that the best way to maintain positions and consistency to place all widgets inside a column or a row or a list. That way the widgets would be aesthetically beautiful regardless of the screen being used for rendering

Comment: i didnt understand your command above, so did you use `Alignment` for that?

Comment: @pskink nope I did not use Alignment. I used the Container, Column and the Padding Widget and it looks much better now.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I did :

```
          Expanded(
        flex: 5,
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 35.0, top: 20.0, right: 35.0, bottom: 30.0),
          color: Colors.white,
          child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 35.0, top: 20.0, right: 35.0, bottom: 30.0),
                child: loginField,
              ),
              new Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 35.0, top: 20.0, right: 35.0, bottom: 30.0),
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    child: Text("Sign up "),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        new MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => new FindMyListings()),
                      );
                      // TODO pass google credentials here in order to get the google my business listings.
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              new Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 35.0, top: 20.0, right: 35.0, bottom: 30.0),
                  child: conditionsApply),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

This is how the screen looks after I made the changes :

[image: Much neater and not as hard wired as in the beginning]